# Submit text from console window into twitter

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter, contenteditable, google-chrome-console

I am sending text to a twitter comment box (see image) from the chrome console by manually editing `public-DraftEditor-content` div in the inspector.

Although the text appears in the comment box, I cannot submit it into my tweet. When I type a tweet manually, then edit the tweet through the code inspector and submit - my edits are cancelled, and the original typed text is submitted as a tweet.

What is the correct way to do this manually or with Javascript/ jQuery?

[image: comment box]

Comment: The issue it is draft and draft does not actually use the value on the screen.

Comment: @epascarello is it some sort of keylogger function on Twitter?